what kind of data is written to events.out.tfevents.1730092600.jolteon.215490.0.v2 from keras.callbacks.tensboard callbacks
Would like to know what kind of information is available and in what format is the file events.out.tfevents.1730092600.jolteon.215490.0.v2 written in.
This file is generated by :
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir, profile_batch=(1,20))

# Train the model with profiling enabled
history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=validation_dataset, epochs=epochs, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

I have tried using
import tensorflow as tf

def extract_event_data(event_file):
    # Load the event file using EventFileLoader
    event_file_loader = tf.compat.v1.train.summary_iterator(event_file)

    for event in event_file_loader:
        # Extract tagged_run_metadata if it exists
        if event.tagged_run_metadata:
            print(f'Event Tagged Metadata: {event.tagged_run_metadata}')
            tag = event.tagged_run_metadata.tag
            run_metadata = event.tagged_run_metadata.run_metadata
            print(f"Tag: {tag}")
            print("Run Metadata (Serialized):", run_metadata)
        
        # Iterate over each value in the summary for metrics or tensor data
        for value in event.summary.value:
            # Print the tag and plugin name if available
            print(f'{value.tag} - {value.metadata.plugin_data.plugin_name}')
            
            # Check and print simple scalar values (e.g., loss, accuracy)
            if value.HasField("simple_value"):
                print(f"Step: {event.step}, Tag: {value.tag}, Value: {value.simple_value}")
            
            # Check and print tensor data, such as histograms or other structured data
            elif value.HasField("tensor"):
                tensor_data = tf.make_ndarray(value.tensor)
                print(f"Step: {event.step}, Tag: {value.tag}, Tensor Shape: {tensor_data.shape}")
                # Optionally, you can print the tensor's content if it's small
                if tensor_data.size < 100:  # Display only small tensors to avoid excessive output
                    print(f"Tensor Data:\n{tensor_data}")
                    
extract_event_data(event_file_path)

for figuring out what kind of data is available but didn't get much.
I am actually looking for the compute graph (with op nodes and their inputs) and the event trace information after profiling.
Any answers are appreciated.

The events.out.tfevents.* files generated by keras.callbacks.TensorBoard in TensorFlow contain logging data, structured in the TensorFlow Events format. These logs store key training and validation metrics as well as other tracked parameters, making them compatible with TensorBoard for interactive visualization. Here’s a breakdown of what data is typically logged in these files:
Scalars: Metrics like loss and accuracy (for both training and validation) at the end of each epoch. If you use custom metrics or add additional data logging, these will also appear in scalar form.
Histograms: If you enable histogram logging, distributions of model weights, gradients, or any other variable can be logged to track changes over time, helping to monitor the training process and detect issues like vanishing or exploding gradients.
Images: You can log images to track visual data transformations, results of certain layers, or outputs from the model during training. This is often used in fields like computer vision.
Text and Custom Logs: Any custom messages or text logs, such as predictions or annotations, that can provide insights into the model’s learning dynamics.
Graph: The model architecture (TensorFlow graph) may also be logged if enabled, providing a visualization of the model’s layers, connections, and data flow in TensorBoard.
Profiling Data: Performance profiling information such as device utilization, memory usage, and other system metrics that are helpful in optimizing model performance.
This data can then be visualized in TensorBoard, allowing you to inspect the model’s behavior and performance over time in an interactive way. The .tfevents file grows with each training epoch as it accumulates this information.
You can programmatically access the data in events.out.tfevents.* files using the tensorflow or tensorboard Python libraries. This approach is useful if you want to analyze the logged metrics without launching TensorBoard or need to use them for custom post-processing.
Here’s how to do it:
Using TensorFlow’s event_accumulator
The tensorboard library provides an event_accumulator module, which allows you to read and parse .tfevents files. Here’s an example:
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing import event_accumulator

# Path to your events file
event_file = 'path/to/your/events.out.tfevents.*'

# Initialize the event accumulator, which loads the event file
ea = event_accumulator.EventAccumulator(event_file)
ea.Reload()  # Load the events data

# Retrieve scalar metrics (like loss and accuracy)
scalars = ea.Tags().get('scalars', [])
for scalar in scalars:
    scalar_events = ea.Scalars(scalar)
    print(f"Metric: {scalar}")
    for event in scalar_events:
        print(f"Step: {event.step}, Value: {event.value}, Wall time: {event.wall_time}")

# Retrieve histogram data
histograms = ea.Tags().get('histograms', [])
for histogram in histograms:
    histogram_events = ea.Histograms(histogram)
    print(f"Histogram: {histogram}")
    for event in histogram_events:
        print(f"Step: {event.step}, Histogram values: {event.histogram_value}")

Access other tags like images, text, or audio in a similar manner

Thank you for the answer @Maksym, I have noticed that .xplane.pd has information on event trace and should have information on graph also but wasn't able to find it.
I have tried using tensorboard_plugin_profile.convert.raw_to_tool_data.xspace_to_tool_data with graph_viewer as the tool but wasn't successful in doing so. Gives me an error 2024-10-30 22:55:35.519939: E tensorflow/python/profiler/internal/profiler_wrapper.cc:171] Can not find HLO module name from options. An error occurred: 
do you have any insights into this or suggest any simpler approach to this?

If accessing graph data through xspace_to_tool_data fails, try directly using TensorFlow's tf.profiler.experimental APIs. You can programmatically load profiling information with tf.profiler.experimental to extract graph and trace events without relying on conversion functions.
import tensorflow as tf
Load the profiling data
tf.profiler.experimental.load_profiler("path/to/logdir")
import tensorflow as tf

I wasn't able to find tf.profiler.experimental.load_profiler in any of the tensorflow documentation. Can you point me towards the documentation please.

I couldn't find a TensorFlow API called tf.profiler.experimental.load_profiler as well. It's possible that this API either does not exist or was deprecated/renamed in favor of other profiling tools within TensorFlow.
To work with profiling data in TensorFlow, you can use the TensorFlow Profiler included with TensorBoard. It provides tools like trace viewers, pod viewers, and recommendations for performance optimization. If you're working with .xplane.pd files, you can use utilities in TensorFlow such as tf.profiler.experimental.start, stop, and trace to analyze performance
